# PHP explode function from checkboxes

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form where I'm submitting some values (from checkboxes) to another page and on that page I'm using an explode function to break the string inside the array. But I'm getting an additional (+1) value when I put the count() function on the explode.

> HTML

```
<form name = "view" method = "POST" action ="cart.php">
<table align = 'center' width = '100%' border = '4'>
<tr>
<td colspan = '20' align = 'center'><h2> Viewing all the Products </h2></td>
</tr>

<tr align = 'center'>
<th>Item ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>

<tr align = 'center' class = "odd">
<?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
    {
        $i_id = $row['item_id'];
        $i_name = $row['item_name'];
        $i_price = $row['item_price'];
        ?>
<td><?php echo $i_id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $i_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $i_price; ?></td>
<?php

$item = $i_name ." ". $i_price;  

?>                                                      
<td><input type="checkbox" name="addcart[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" onClick="return KeepCount()" />Tick</td> 
</tr>
<?php  }?><input type = "hidden" name = "check">
<button type=  "submit" onclick = "location.href = 'cart.php';" id = "cart">Add to Cart</button> <?php }  ?>  
</table>

</form>
```

> PHP (on page 2)

```
 $prd = implode(",",$_POST['addcart']);
 $final = explode(",", $prd);
 for($i=0; $i<=count($final); $i++)
 {
 echo count($final);   //this is where I'm getting the +1 to original count and hence everything falls apart.
 echo $final[$i];
 }
```

> Note: I have include all the essential files like config.php and everything in the PHP file already.

Comment: check the `var_dump($final)`, exploded array. And why are you imploding at first place? Its in array already right ?

Comment: Most probably your values submitted in `addcart` checkboxes contain a comma. If it is your original intention (addcart having several comma-separated values) then you should not worry about count changing. If it is not, joining the array then splitting it back does not make sense.

Comment: I got it guys. I can't believe I missed that -.-

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why that much extra code, directly do like below:-

```
 foreach($_POST['addcart'] as $val){
   echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since count() starts counting from 1 and for loop starting from 0.

Replace this line:

`for($i=0; $i<=count($final); $i++)`

with

`for($i=0; $i<=count($final)-1; $i++)`

Comment: why does it take +1 in the first place?

Comment: @MuneerKhan since you are counting array elements, `count()` function starts counting from **1**